# Rails logging failure, or client-side issues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, devise

I support a Rails 4 app used for remote project reporting. One of the team insists that she used the tool on several occasions to report her data, double-checked it to ensure it had been entered properly, then later discovered it was all gone. I found evidence of her authentication (Devise gem) in the production logs, but no trace of her reporting activity--not even the GET requests that would be necessary to begin her work.

Is it even possible for Rails to suppress logging events in this manner, when they are working for every other user?

If it is not possible, does it suggest that the claim is unreliable? (trust me, I'm not pre-assuming this)

Unfortunately, the user is no longer involved in the project and is not responding to requests. Also, the absence of necessary POST events is borne out by a client-facing logging feature as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails logs all requests the moment a GET hits the server, before authentication happens. It is most improbable that logged requests by a single user can be suppressed, unless the default middleware stack is modified.

I'd go with Occam's Razor.